# Is it possible to access Google Translate offline?

Tags: google-translate

Is there an implementation - be it either through a Chrome app or native Linux software - that allows me to use Google Translate while being offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Google Translate Android application](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142473?hl=en) offline if you download the languages. [Athtek Software](http://www.athtek.com/)'s website lists a free Google Desktop Translator. I haven't tried either one.

Comment: Now I just need to find a solution how to run this Android app on my Ubuntu Linux system. Thanks!